# Why am I getting segmentation fault(core dumped)?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, arguments, format-specifiers

I was solving a problem from a CodeChef contest [Link to the problem](https://www.codechef.com/problems/SNAPCHAT), when I came across this error.
My code was:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
       int n;
       int max=0;
       int count=0;
       int a[n];
       int b[n];
       scanf("%d",&n);
       for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
       {
           scanf("%d",&a[j]);
       }
       for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
       {
           scanf("%d",&b[k]);
       }
     for(int x=0;x<n;x++)
        {
           if(a[x]&&b[x]!=0)
           {
               count=count+1;
           }
           else
           {
               if(count>max)
               {max=count;
               count=0;}
           }
       }
       if(count>max)
         max=count;
       printf("%d", max);
    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I saw another similar problem on stack which said that the solution was to change the argument of the function but the void argument type in `int main` was given by the contest website itself so I don't think that should be the problem.

Comment: `int a[n];` is invalid C++ (`n` is not even initialized, so even in C it would be problematic), use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Aside:  ```count++``` is the same as ```count = count + 1```. So is ```count += 1```. ```if (a[i] && b[i] != 0```, here ```b[i]``` is the same as ```b[i] != 0```, pick one and be consistent with it.  Spacebar makes for readability, use it.

Answer (score 1):

What Jarod42 said solved the question. The problem was just that I did not take input in my length variable **n** before declaring the arrays **a[n]** and **b[n]**.Moving the scanf line to just after declaring n seems to work.

```
   int n;
   scanf("%d",&n);
```

Instead of

```
   int n;
   int max=0;
   int count=0;
   int a[n];
   int b[n];
   scanf("%d",&n);
```

Thank you everyone for contributing.